# How to customize storyboard with code based on device in xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, storyboard, iad, appdelegate

How do I customize my storyboard look and feel in code. I want to have different coordinates for an iAd banner based on the device it is running on.

Comment: What code for storyboard!!!! There is nothing like that. Yo can not code anything for storyboard.